# How to group equal values in J?

Tags: j

```
   (= <@#"1 0 ~.) 3 2 3 3 4
+-----+-+-+
|3 3 3|2|4|
+-----+-+-+
```

What other ways are there? I mostly don’t like the part where it says `"1 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The adverb [key](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/slashdot#dyadic) (`/.`) groups the right argument as specified by the left argument and applies a verb to each group. If you give it the same left and right argument you can apply the verb [box](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/lt) (`<`) to group all the equal items

```
   </.~ 3 2 3 3 4
┌─────┬─┬─┐
│3 3 3│2│4│
└─────┴─┴─┘
```

You could easily sum the groups instead:

```
   +//.~ 3 2 3 3 4
9 2 4
```